# Calling a C function from Objective-C with string array

Tags: objective-c, c, string

I'm trying to call a simple tutorial C function from Objective-C and I can't figure out how to split up the arguments being passed, which is two strings.

```
int cFunction(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    printf("argc = %d\n", argc);
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d] = \"%s\"\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried `cFunction(3, "string1 string2")`, `cFunction(3, "string1", "string2")`, and `cFunction(3, args)`, with `args` being an NSArray composed of `[textField1 stringValue]` and `[textField2 stringValue]`

I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to `printf argv[i]`. I've also tried passing 2 as the value of argc.

How should this be called? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this function parameter list, `argv` is a pointer to a C string array (`char **`).

Using the Objective-C `NSString` or `NSArray` type isn't possible with this function, First, convert each string using `-(const char *)cStringUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;`, and store them into a C array of strings.

```
// myString is "arg1"
// mySecondString is "arg2"
char *cString = [myString
                 cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
char *cSecondString = [mySecondString
                       cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
char *myStrings[2] = { cString, cSecondString };
int returnCode = cFunction(2, myStrings);
```

This should work.

Comment: Ah, sorry I forgot I tried that last night. I don't get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I do that, but the two strings are both being assigned to argv[0] and I'm trying to get them into argv[0] and argv[1]. Or do I just need to have the cFunction split them on whitespace?

Comment: You could break a string on whitespaces, but in order to pass the function an array of C strings, you will need to reserve spa ce for the array, and store the pointers to each C string into it.

Comment: I'm making my args by appending textField2 to textField1, with a @" " in between, and my cFunction has "textField1string textField2string" in it.

Comment: Ah so you're saying make my NSArray hold the *cStrings instead of the [textField stringValue]s and then pass the NSArray?

Comment: no, you should define and allocate a C string array `char **`.

Comment: for example : `char * array [4] = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};`.

Comment: read carefully the function body, it loops over the elements of the array, printing each turn the string at index `i` (`argv[i]`).